# How to add files to Internal Storage in the project

Tags: android, storage, internal

I have some configuration files that should be editable. I need to add all of them to the project before creating the .apk file. Also they should remain private to the application, then I guess that they should go in the Internal Storage. 
Is it possible to do? In which folder should I put them.

One of the solutions I found is to add them to assets and move to Internal Storage in the first run, but files size is too big to duplicate the memory.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have some configuration files that should be editable. I need to add all of them to the project before creating the .apk file.

By default, those two concepts are mutually exclusive. Files that are in your APK (e.g., in `assets/`) cannot be edited.

> One of the solutions I found is to add them to assets and move to Internal Storage in the first run, but files size is too big to duplicate the memory.

Then make smaller files. This is your only option that even comes close to meeting your requirements.